Date Range Falls in Between Another Date Range - Google Sheets
I'm trying to find out if a date range falls between another date range in order to create a Gantt Chart in Google Sheets. However, I can't seem to wrap my head around it.
Project Start Date: 10/1/2024

Project End Date: 10/1/2025
Date Range to check: 01/01/2025 to 01/31/2025
I wanted to write a formula that checks if 01/01/2025 to 01/31/2025 falls between 10/1/2024 and 10/1/2025.
Here is the spreadsheet

Please share a formatted text table with your sample data.

Here is the spreadsheet.

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

You can simply check whether the start date is later than the reference start date and the end date is earlier than the reference end date:
=AND(C3>=$A$3, D3<=$B$3)


In your case, you can also use one formula to fill in the entire row. Same idea, but using ARRAYFORMULA and two nested IFs:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:2>=$B$5, IF(D3:3<=$C$5, TRUE, FALSE),FALSE))


References

AND
ARRAYFORMULA
IF


=AND(C3>=$A$3, D3<=$B$3)
I tweaked the formula a little bit and got the results that I wanted. Thank you! This is very helpful!

See how to accept @DorcasDomingo

As an alternative, you may use this;
=BYCOL(D2:O2,LAMBDA(Ø,AND(Ø>=B5,EOMONTH(Ø,0)<=C5)))

